# How to have a different models.ForeignKey related_name for each linked objects of same model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, orm

I’m working with Django Rest to have multiple “text block” objects linked with the document object. I’ve accomplished this with a simple models.ForeignKey feature so far.

However, I’m rendering all of these text blocks in multiple columns in the front end.
The Textblock model will have a column field to determine which goes to which column. Since the order of these text blocks matter, I was afraid of having them all mixed together under single "all_columns" field
So far, I figured the easiest way is to let DRF return something like the following:

```
{
    "name": "Comparing Two Characters",
    "column_A": [
        {
            "title": "Text Block",
            "body": "lorem ipsum blah blah"
            "col": 1
        }
    ],
    "column_B": [
        {
            "title": "Text Block 2",
            "body": "lorem ipsum blah blah"
            "col": 2
        },
            {
            "title": "Text Block 3",
            "body": "lorem ipsum blah blah"
            "col": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I be able to implement something like this? I’m not sure if using related fields is even ideal for such cases. I would appreciate any help!

Here’s my current models.py code for reference:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # other fields
    def __str__(self):
            return self.name

class TextBlock(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, related_name='blocks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    col = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

### Edit:

What I'm getting returned with the updated code by sayeed910

```
            "name": "outlineblock-test",
            "desc": "",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "url": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/layoutblocks/7/",
                    "col": 3,
                    "title": "col3",
                    "placeholder": "hehehe",
                    "template": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/templates/3/"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/layoutblocks/6/",
                    "col": 2,
                    "title": "col2",
                    "placeholder": "hehe",
                    "template": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/templates/3/"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/layoutblocks/5/",
                    "col": 1,
                    "title": "col1",
                    "placeholder": "haha",
                    "template": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/templates/3/"
                }
            ],
```

serializers.py

```
class TextBlockSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = TextBlock
       fields = '__all__'

class DocumentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    blocks = LayoutBlockSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Document
       fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: How do you determine which block is in which column? Are there any queries and serializers you have already written?

Comment: @sayeed910 just edited the post with clarification! The Textblock will have a column field. But since the order of these text blocks matter, I was afraid of having them all mixed together under single "all_columns" field

Comment: I've a few more questions. How is the order of the blocks determined? Is it the order of creation? How would you translate `col = 1` into `column_A`? Your col is a `CharField` but the serialized version is `int`. Is there some logic or is it arbitrary?

Comment: @sayeed910 it was just a quick demonstration but yes it should've been IntegerField. As for the order of the blocks, the blocks already exist in a new document pre-ordered; but users are able to drag them around and add them. The order should follow the predestined order and new blocks will be added to the bottom.

Comment: What is `LayoutBlockSerializer`?

Comment: should be TextBlockSerializer; I have different model names in my actual code so I'm keep making the same mistakes sorry

Comment: I've updated my answer. See if it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Document(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # other fields
    def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    def blocks_by_column(self):
        block_group = defaultdict(list)
        for block in self.blocks.all():
            block_group[block.col].append(block)
        return block_group


class TextBlock(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, related_name='blocks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    col = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

If you have a ordering mechanism i.e. an order column, you can change `self.blocks.all()` to `self.blocks.order_by(<column>).all()`. You can later change the keys of `blocks_group` as you see fit. `1 -> column_A`.

### As Per OP's Edit:

You should perform the grouping operation in the serializer instead of the model

```
from collections import defaultdict

class DocumentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    blocks = LayoutBlockSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        block_group = defaultdict(list)
        for block in ret["blocks"]:
            block_group[block["col"]].append(block)
        ret["blocks"] = dict(block_group)
        return ret

    class Meta:
       model = Document
       fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! I tried the code above, but I'm somehow still getting the same results as before with TextBlock listed under "blocks". I tried adding "block_group" as a field in my serializer, but I got "Field name `block_group` is not valid for model `Template`." error. I added more details in the edit for my original post.

Comment: this worked! 
Last question: how would I implement the ordering mechanism now that `self.blocks.all()` changed to `ret["blocks"]`?

Comment: `ret["blocks"]` contains the serialized value from your `TextBlockSerializer`. So, if you want to implement ordering, you have to do so in there. Alternatively, you can sort the `ret["blocks"]` using `sorted`.